# How do I build bash to patch against shellshock and test it before installing it at the root of my system?

Tags: linux, bash, security, shellshock

What seems to be wrong with my code below? I'm downloading and patching up to patch 18 which I understand is the patch for shellchock vulnerability. But I still get the vulnerability when running Bash.

Download source and patches

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1.tar.gz
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1-patches/bash31-00{1..9} http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1-patches/bash31-0{10..18}
```

Unpack and apply patches

```
tar -xvf bash-3.1.tar.gz
cd bash-3.1
find ../bash31-??? -exec /bin/sh -c 'patch -p0 <{}' \;
```

*(Asside: the find command above just happens to return a sorted list because of shell globbing, but I know this is not always true for the find find)*

Config, Make, Make Install

```
./configure --prefix /tmp/bash_patched && make && make install
```

Run bash

```
/tmp/bash_patched/bin/bash
```

The following should return `/tmp/bash_patched/bin/bash 3.1.18(1)-release`

```
echo $BASH $BASH_VERSION
```

Do the shellshock test

```
env X="() { :;} ; echo busted" /bin/sh -c "echo stuff"
```

For me this returns

```
busted
stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the test `/bin/sh` remains vulnerable on the system until installing at the root. A better test would be `env X="() { :;} ; echo busted" /tmp/bash_patched/bin/bash -c "echo stuff"`

Answer (score 0):

The shellshock patches are actualy 19 and 20. The wget is not downloading those. Haven't tested it yet but changing the second command to

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1-patches/bash31-00{1..9} http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1-patches/bash31-0{10..19} http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-3.1-patches/bash31-020
```

should make it work

Comment: the version I'm seeing is 3-1.20(1) - ok my fault - the patches start from 18. these are actually the later updates patching the other related issues

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at the script described in Super User question 816787? It worked like a champ for my Ubuntu machines, about 15 min per server including VMware snapshots, with no reboot required.